# Eclipse project creation not working for Oracle ADF Essentials

Tags: eclipse, jpa, oracle-adf

Based of this Guide [Oracle ADF Tools Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E47843_06/12124/OEPUG/oracle_adf_tools.htm#BABBBCGB), I tried to create an ADF Application, but I encounter an error in JPA Project Wizard.

No library providers are available for this facet. The facet cannot be installed.

Anyone faced this issue

Versions are latest:

- ADF Essentials 12.2.1.2
- GlashhFish 4
- Eclipse OEPE-12.2.1.4-neon

Comment: which version of ADF Essential you are using? are you using the eclipse provided by the oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using latest versions you can try following steps in the eclipse wizard

This has no reference sites, I observed this by doing it my PC

1. Choose JPA Version 2.1
2. Choose Oracle ADF 12.2.1 Web Project - from the configuration drop
   down

   1. You will encounter an error "JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires Dynamic Web module 2.5 or newer"
3. Click "Modify" button
4. Tick the checkbox "Dynamic Web Module" and change version to 3.1
5. Tick the checkbox "GlassFish Web Extentions"
6. Click "Ok"
7. Click "Next" "Next"
8. Choose "EclipseLink 2.5.x"
9. Choose "GlassFish System Library"
10. Choose the oracle 11g connection as per your documentation URL
11. Click "Next"
12. Tick "Generate web.xml deployment descriptor"
13. Click "Next"
14. Choose "GlassFish System Library"
15. Click "Next"
16. Choose "JSTL Library from Glassfish"
17. Click "Next"
18. Tick the checkbox "ADF Essentials Client WAR" as per your document URL
19. Click "Finish"

I think the error which you are facing will be solved

Comment: The error is not appearing when I am using these steps, I hope oracle will update the documentations and screenshots soon